# Can you build a new model based on the current ModelState

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-binding

I am trying to build a object/model in memory that is a representation of what the model would look like if the current ModelState was assumed to be correct and was Merged into the model.

I thought I would look into the source code for `TryUpdateModel()` or `UpdateModel()` and came up with the following:

```
private T GetTempModel<T>(T model, ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
        {
            var mtype = Type.GetType(model.GetType().FullName);
            var m = Activator.CreateInstance(mtype);
            var binder = ModelBinders.Binders.GetBinder(mtype);

            var bc = new ModelBindingContext()
            {
                ModelMetadata = ModelMetadataProviders.Current.GetMetadataForType(() => m, mtype),
                ModelName = null,
                ModelState = filterContext.Controller.ViewData.ModelState, 
                ValueProvider = filterContext.Controller.ValueProvider
            };

            var result = binder.BindModel(filterContext.Controller.ControllerContext, bc);
            return (T)result;

        }
```

However when I do this the `result` value is just the default state that was created when I ran the `CreateInstance()`.  It didn't merge all the proposed values in the ModelState.

Am I misunderstanding how this should work?  Is there a way to get a model representation of the items in `ModelState` in object form instead of KeyValuePair?

**UPDATE**:  Additional information per comments.

I am simplifying this a bit but here is the basic scenario for what I am doing.  Let's say I have a survey application.  The user logs in and is presented with a basic View where they enter their profile information (first, last name etc.)  The viewModel used to generate this view has a property, `SurveyQuestions`, that is initialized with no questions. As they navigate through the next screens they are prompted with questions, these questions are loaded into the View/DOM via AJAX for performance reasons as they answer one question I go grab the next applicable one.

When the user is complete and POSTs the survey I get everything as expected in the ViewModel and in `SurveyQuestions` I can see all their questions/answer information (`List<QuestionBlock>`).

However I am using the Post-Redirect-Get (PRG) pattern and if there is an exception during the POST I store the `ModelState`, redirect, and reapply the `ModelState` upon exiting the GET.  The problem is that in the GET the ViewModel is just the uninitialized and empty question `SurveyQuestions` property.  Because of this the `ModelState` values aren't initialized properly for the `SurveyQuestions` when the view is rendered.  All other properties get the correct `ModelState` values when the view is rendered.

This is because I have to initialize the user's `SurveyQuestions` to have each of the question information before exiting the GET.

This is where I would like to read the values from the `ModelState` into a temporary object so that I can access them and rebuild those questions server side to correctly rendered in the view.

Comment: shouldn't there be a command to add the new object to the application's models collections?

Comment: I can't think of a use case. Please explain what makes you require this?

Comment: Well, the `ModelState` dictionary is by design used for your model's validation errors mainly, and for that you are assumed to have some viewmodel properties that are validatable. I can't understand what it would even mean "to get a model representation of the items in `ModelState`" as your model object.